# Validity standard for GeoJSON polygons?

Tags: polygon, geojson, ogc

There are two different ways the polygon below can be represented:

[image: polygon with hole touching shell]

- In ESRI-land, the polygon would be modeled as a single exterior ring that loops back on itself.
- In the OGC world, it would be modeled as a polygon with an exterior ring and an interior ring.

Does the GeoJSON format require that either one of these approaches be used over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Polygons are not simple to handle and there are more than two worlds. I recommend to read this article "About Invalid, Valid and Clean Polygons" http://www.springer.com/%3FSGWID%3D5-102-45-124048-p32597622

The GeoJSON specification https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946 says that "GeoJSON comprises the seven concrete geometry types defined in the OpenGIS Simple Features Implementation Specification for SQL [SFSQL]". You can get that one from http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=829 and try to understand it. I couldn't really. However, the authors of the "About Invalid, Valid and Clean Polygons" have made a test with test polygon 4b (pages 10 and 11) and result was "R3". I guess that it means that by OGC Simple Feature Access the self-touching outer ring is invalid and therefore it should be invalid in GeoJSON as well. But somehow I fear that interpretations in real life may vary.

Given that GeoJSON is to large extent a MapBox driven standard, this ticket about MapBox vector tiles https://github.com/tilezen/mapbox-vector-tile/issues/63 suggest that it would be better to avoid writing self-touching outer boundaries. However, programs which read GeoJSON should probably accept both variants.